# Python: How to parse a date from text formatted like excel's "full date"?

Tags: python, datetime, text-parsing

I have a CSV report (from a system that I have no control) with the date column in the format "Quarta-feira, 1 de Janeiro de 2020", which I believe corresponds to the [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) '%A, %d de %B de %Y' with pt-br locale.

I need to create a datetime like object from such string but I am trying this without success.

```
import locale
import pandas as pd

locale.set(locale.LC_TIME, 'pt_BR.utf8')

pd.to_datetime("Quarta-feira, 1 de Janeiro de 2020", format="A%, %d de %B de %Y")
```

Does anyone knows how could I do that?

p.s.:

- I am aware that I could remove the "Quarta-feira," from the string and it will work with `format="%d de %B de %Y"`.
- I don't need to work with pandas, it can be any date/time lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051389/pandas-parse-non-english-string-dates) and noting that you don't mind using additional libs. You can use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This worked like a charm for me:

```
#!pip install dateparser
import dateparser
t = "Quarta-feira, 1 de Janeiro de 2020"
dateparser.parse(t)
>>datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: That's beautiful.
Thank you!