# Python - Transform/Change a date format

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a problem which is changing the date format from '21 Sep 2022 04:37:17' to '2022-09-21 04:37:17'.
I'm using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
fileIn = 'C:/Users/xxx.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(fileIn, index_col=0)
diaStrava = df['Data da atividade'].str[:2]
mesStrava = df['Data da atividade'].str[6:9]
anoStrava = df['Data da atividade'].str[13:18]
if mesStrava == 'out':
    c_mesStrava = '10'
dataStrava = diaStrava + '-' + c_mesStrava + '-' + anoStrava
```

And I'm getting the error:

...
Traceback (most recent call last):

...
if mesStrava == 'out':
... in **nonzero**
raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the date format using string manipulation, you could instead [convert the string to datetime and then back to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38067805/14020202). See [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [Series.dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)

---should work, although this line might be problematic since it's not in English

```py
if mesStrava == 'out':
```

Consider using [dateparser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051390/14020202) to parse non-English dates.

Answer (score 0):

- firstly, create the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data da atividade':['21 Sep 2022 04:37:17']})
print(df)
```

- secondly, transfer

```py
print(pd.to_datetime(df['Data da atividade']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```